Shibboleth IdP Upgrade from idp3 to idp 4
I'm currently working on upgrading our Shibboleth IdP from version 3 to version 4. After modifying the configuration files in IdP, we are encountering an issue with the SAML response. The error manifests as an HTML page displaying an "Uncaught Exception" message, as shown in the attached screenshot: Web Login-uncaught exception.Web Login-uncaught exception
Here is the relevant portion of the log file:
2024-07-29 12:50:12,576 - 127.0.0.1 - ERROR [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile:39] - Uncaught runtime exception
org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An ELException occurred getting the value for expression 'PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:104)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts': 'Error creating bean with name 'PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts' defined in class path resource [net/shibboleth/idp/flows/saml/saml-abstract-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'artifactImpliesSecureChannel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [yourSecureChannel]'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:215)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts' defined in class path resource [net/shibboleth/idp/flows/saml/saml-abstract-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'artifactImpliesSecureChannel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [yourSecureChannel]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'artifactImpliesSecureChannel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [yourSecureChannel]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:600)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [yourSecureChannel]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:154)

We made modifications to the Shibboleth IdP configuration files to align with our requirements for the upgrade from version 3 to version 4.
Our expectation was that these changes would enable the IdP to process SAML requests and generate valid SAML responses correctly, in compliance with SAML specifications. This would ensure seamless authentication and single sign-on (SSO) functionality for our users.
However, we are encountering a runtime exception related to the PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts bean, which is preventing the IdP from generating the expected SAML responses.

Please provide your configuration files, specifically the issue seems to be in saml-abstract-beans.xml (Invalid boolean value [yourSecureChannel])

Thank you J Asgarov for your response. Starting from Shibboleth IdP version 4, several configuration files, including saml-abstract-beans.xml, have been removed from the system folder.
Here are  details about my project versions:
Shibboleth IdP Version 3.4.4 upgrading to 4.3.3
Java version='17.0.10' vendor='Eclipse Adoptium'
java.vm.version=17.0.10+7

but the error message references the file net/shibboleth/idp/flows/saml/saml-abstract-beans.xml?

Thank you for pointing that out. I have been trying to locate where it is referencing net/shibboleth/idp/flows/saml/saml-abstract-beans.xml, but I haven’t been able to find it. Since this file is no longer available from version 4 onwards, I'm struggling to identify the appropriate configuration or replacement. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
